# Dense Cantor set approximation

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am reading “Measure, Topology and Fractal Geometry” by Edgar, and in the first few pages he defines the Cantor set and a dense approximation to the Cantor set. He says that $\frac{1}{4} = 0.02020202\ldots$ is in the Cantor set because any point that has a representation in base 3 consisting only of $0$s and $2$s is in the Cantor set. This makes sense to me because we only delete the middle third (which can be represented by a 1).

He next gives a construction for a dense approximation to the Cantor set via point translations:
\begin{align}
L_0 &= \{0\}, & s_0 &= \frac{2}{3}, \\
L_n &= L_{n-1}\cup (L_{n-1}+s_n), & s_n &= \frac{1}{3}s_{n-1}, \\
L &= \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}L_k.
\end{align}

He then argues “The points in $L_k$ are the numbers in $[0, 1]$ that have a base-3 representation with $k$ digits involving only $0$s and $2$s”. He says that $\frac{1}{4}$ is not in $L$ and hence $L\neq$ Cantor set. This seems contradictory to me. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, wouldn’t an infinite number of $0$s and $2$s represented as $0.02020202\ldots$ be in $L$?

Perhaps I don’t understand $L = \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}L_k$, because wouldn’t it mean that:
$$\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}L_k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=0}^nL_k \ni 0.020202\ldots\ ?$$

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way. If $0.020202\ldots \in L = \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} L_k$, then there is $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0.020202\ldots \in L_K$, but this is not true by the definition of $L_K$. Therefore $0.020202\ldots \not\in L$.

**Added Later:** By construction, $L_K$ consists of those $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $x$ has a ternary representation which has $K$ digits, each one a $0$ or a $2$. Therefore, $\frac{1}{4} = 020202\ldots \not\in L_K$ for any $K$ (because it has more than $K$ digits).

Comment: If I understand what you are saying then this is because we cannot perform a finite amount of translations in order to obtain an infinitely long number? Then I guess my limit definition is not equal to the natural number definition.

Comment: I am not saying anything about translations, all I am using is the definition of union. Your definition of $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}L_k$ doesn't make any sense to me; what does it mean to take the limit of sets?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your reasoning for $0.02020202$ not being in $L_k$ by definition of $L_k$ then?

Comment: I meant $0.02020202...$ of course.